# Read Dependency HttpRequest and HttpResponse Content in a non-blocking way in Application Insights Telemetry Initializers

Tags: c#, asynchronous, .net-core, azure-application-insights

I have an application in .net core 3.1 using Application Insights sdk for telemetry. I have the below code for logging dependency response body in App insights dependency telemetry. However, this:`var responseBody = httpResponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().GetAwaiter().GetResult();` being a blocking call is causing thread starvation resulting in latencies for the services' users. I cannot make the method async Task as the interface `ITelemtryInitializer` doesn't support it. Is there a way to make this non-blocking or any other way to do the same without thread starvation?

```
public class DependencyEnhanceInitializer : ITelemetryInitializer
{
    public void Initialize(ITelemetry telemetry)
    {
        var dependecyTelemetry = telemetry as DependencyTelemetry;
        if (dependecyTelemetry == null) return;

        if (dependecyTelemetry.TryGetOperationDetail("HttpResponse", out object response)
            && response is HttpResponseMessage httpResponse)
        {
            var responseBody = httpResponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().GetAwaiter().GetResult();
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(responseBody))
                dependecyTelemetry.Properties.Add("ResponseBody", responseBody);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Put code into a BackGroundWorker.

Comment: How do I do that? This code is executed after dotnet core's automatic dependency collector. So, I need to have the auto generated data along with the response content. I can't send the dependencyTelemetry to a queue or somewhere else because that would make the blocking issue worse

Comment: *Don't* use a BackgroundWorker for any reason. It's an obsolete class used in Winforms to run jobs in the background without freezing the UI. You already have asynchronous operations here. The real problem is the `Initialize` method itself - if it wants to call asynchronous methods, it *must* be asynchronous itself. Besides, `.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().` will *consume* the response which is almost certainly not what you want

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK there is no way to avoid this situation.  The [MS-Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.compilerservices.taskawaiter?view=netframework-4.8#properties) for .NET says

> "This API supports the product infrastructure and is not intended to be used directly from your code."

**[ReadAsStringAsync()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpcontent.readasstringasync?view=net-6.0#system-net-http-httpcontent-readasstringasync)** method Serialize the HTTP content to a string as an asynchronous operation. So we need to wait untill the **GetAwaiter()** and **GetResult()** to complete the asynchronous operation.

So, you have to wait until the entire Request/Response serialize the HTTP content to a string as an asynchronous operation.  The way you are using is the recommended approach of .NET.

```cs
httpResponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().GetAwaiter().GetResult();
```

Refer the [blog](https://www.nikouusitalo.com/blog/why-is-getawaiter-getresult-bad-in-c/) of Niko Uusitalo for detailed information